# How do I programmatically add a readonly or disable attribute to a form input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular application with a form. I would like to temporarily turn two of the inputs fields into a `readonly` or `disable` state. How do I programmatically add a `readonly` or `disable` attribute to these form input?

Find below my angular `component.html` code:

```
<div>
   <div class="group material-input">
      <input [(ngModel)] ="phone[0]" type="text" id="phoneTab1" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Phone Number</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group material-input">
      <input [(ngModel)] ="amount[0]" type="text" id="amountTab1" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Amount</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="sign-btn text-center">
     <a (click)="makeMPESAPayment(1)" class="btn btn-lg btn-gradient-01 text-white">
        Skuma
     </a>
</div>
```

...in the `component.ts` code I have tried the code below which hasnt worked at all:

I have tried with `document.getElementById("phoneTab1").disabled = true;` and 
`document.getElementById("phoneTab1").disabled = true;`

How do I programmatically add a readonly or disable attribute to these form input?

Comment: Programmatically set a property (`this.thingDisabled = true`) then bind the result (`[disabled]="thingDisabled"`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your prompt response, your solution works, however not perfectly. When the text field is disable. the label moves from above the input filed and covers the text field along with its contents. How do I disable the input field, and maintain the label above the text field?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a property isDisabled type boolean for example on your component.ts, and use it in your template : [disabled] = 'isDisabled'.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, though I haven't tried it out yet, does your solution move the input field label over the disabled field?

Comment: Welcome, you can use isDisabled where you want, to set an element disabled or not.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt response. I just tried out your solution and realised that the element gets disabled alright, however, when the element is disabled, the label moves back down from above the field to its original position in the input field, making it look messy.

Comment: thats is depend on your css, if you are using bootsrap just add 'form-inline' class to your form my solve your issue. :)